# Append one line at the top of huge gzip file

Tags: linux, shell, logging

I have a huge gzip file (~400MB). I want to append one line of text at the BEGINNING of the file.

I was thinking of creating a gzip file with the header line and then using `zcat` to combine header file and log file. Just wanted to check if there is a better/elegant/efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

two gzipped files concatenated to a single file is actually a valid gz file.

Try it.

Gzip your first, single line that you want to prepend, then cat the two to a third.

```
print "My newline" | gzip -c > /tmp/smallzip.gz
cat /tmp/smallzip.gz mybigfile.gz > newbigfile.gz
```

That would save the time and cpu of unzipping the big gz file, prepending your line and rezipping, which would be:

```
(
    echo "My newline"
    zcat bigfile.gz
) | gzip -c > newbifile.gz
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description. I think you want `cat` rather than `zcat`. (I haven't yet confirmed that it works.)

Comment: that code would be to prepend the new line to the unzipped big file, and rezip.  I'll edit it just now.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
gzip < newlineoftext > newfile.gz
cat oldfile.gz >> newfile.gz
```

(Because, as another answer already pointed out, two gzipped files concatenated together is a valid gzip file.)